# Scala-cats, compose Reader with ReaderT

Tags: scala, composition, monad-transformers, scala-cats, reader-monad

Here is a small composition of functions, all of which return `ReaderT`:

```
  type FailFast[A] = Either[List[String], A]

  def f1:ReaderT[FailFast, Map[String,String], Boolean] = ReaderT(_ => Right(true))
  def f2:ReaderT[FailFast, Map[String,String], Boolean] = ReaderT(_ => Left(List("d")))
  def f3:ReaderT[FailFast, Map[String,String], Boolean] = ReaderT(_ => Right(true))
  def f4:ReaderT[FailFast, Map[String,String], Boolean] = ReaderT(_ => Right(true))

  def fc:ReaderT[FailFast, Map[String,String], Boolean] =
    f1.flatMap( b1 => {
      if (b1)
        for {
          b2 <- f2
          b3 <- f3
          b4 <- f4
        } yield b4
      else ReaderT(_ => Right(true))
    })
```

How to implement `fc` in case `f1` would return `Reader`, but not `ReaderT`:

```
def f1:Reader[Map[String,String], Boolean] = Reader(_ => true)
```

Now I have to compose `Reader`, which is exactly `ReaderT[Id, ...]` with `Reader[FailFast, ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned `Reader[A, B]` is just `ReaderT[Id, A, B]` (which is itself just an type alias of `Kleisli[Id, A, B]`).

Since you are using cats there is a method called `mapK` which maps over the first type parameter of `ReaderT`, you just need to provide a `FunctionK/~>` instance for the conversion. So in your case it would look something like this:

```
val Id2FailFast = new (Id ~> FailFast) {
  def apply[T](f: Id[T]): FailFast[T] = Right(f) 
}

f1.mapK(Id2FailFast).flatMap( b1 => {
  if (b1)
    for {
      b2 <- f2
      b3 <- f3
      b4 <- f4
    } yield b4
  else ReaderT(_ => Right(true))
})
```

There are likely some other refactorings that could clean it up further, like using an `EitherT` but since it seems like a bit of a contrived example I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thank you. I tried to use this approach, but with some mistakes, used mapF instead of mapK, and withoout Id2FailFast helper function could not convert it appropriately. The only change I had to apply into your solution is to change f type from Id to Id[T]. Without it I got an error : type Id takes type parameters
    def apply[T](f: Id): FailFast[T] = Right(f)